# Mongodb: When find result items more than about 80000, the find operation become very slow

Tags: mongodb

I create compound index:

```
db.dailyWork.createIndex({"companyId": 1, "salaryMonth":1, "employeeId":1})
```

and, I RUN command explain's result is good:

```
db.dailyWork.find({"companyId" : ObjectId("60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5"),"salaryMonth" : "2022-09"}).explain("executionStats")

{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "cowboy.dailyWork",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "companyId" : {
                                                "$eq" : ObjectId("60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5")
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "salaryMonth" : {
                                                "$eq" : "2022-09"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "companyId" : 1,
                                        "salaryMonth" : 1,
                                        "employeeId" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "companyId_1_salaryMonth_1_employeeId_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "companyId" : [ ],

"salaryMonth" : [ ],
                                        "employeeId" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "companyId" : [
                                                "[ObjectId('60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5'), ObjectId('60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5')]"
                                        ],
                                        "salaryMonth" : [
                                                "[\"2022-09\", \"2022-09\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "employeeId" : [
                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "companyId" : {
                                                "$eq" : ObjectId("60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5")
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "salaryMonth" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "salaryMonth_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "salaryMonth" : [ ]
                                        },

"isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "salaryMonth" : [
                                                        "[\"2022-09\", \"2022-09\"]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "salaryMonth" : {
                                                "$eq" : "2022-09"
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "companyId" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "companyId_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "companyId" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "companyId" : [
                                                        "[ObjectId('60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5'), ObjectId('60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5')]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 88078,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 183,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 88078,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 88078,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "nReturned" : 88078,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 151,
                        "works" : 88079,
                        "advanced" : 88078,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 691,
                        "restoreState" : 691,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 88078,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 88078,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 30,
                                "works" : 88079,
                                "advanced" : 88078,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 691,
                                "restoreState" : 691,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "companyId" : 1,
                                        "salaryMonth" : 1,
                                        "employeeId" : 1,

 },
                                "indexName" : "companyId_1_salaryMonth_1_employeeId_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "companyId" : [ ],
                                        "salaryMonth" : [ ],
                                        "employeeId" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "companyId" : [
                                                "[ObjectId('60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5'), ObjectId('60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5')]"
                                        ],
                                        "salaryMonth" : [
                                                "[\"2022-09\", \"2022-09\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "employeeId" : [
                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                        ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 88078,
                                "seeks" : 1,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "izwz9j7ffkk3uyach8aflfz",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.4.10",
                "gitVersion" : "078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

but I get different result from my node server. It's the same query condition:

```
{
    "op": "query",
    "ns": "cowboy.dailyWork",
    "query": {
        "find": "dailyWork",
        "filter": {
            "$and": [{
                    "companyId": ObjectId("60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5")
                }, {
                    "salaryMonth": "2022-09"
                }
            ]
        },
        "sort": {
            "_id": 1
        },
        "projection": {
            "employeeId": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "amount": 1
        },
        "returnKey": false,
        "showRecordId": false
    },
    "cursorid": 70514389445,
    "keysExamined": 29726623,
    "docsExamined": 29726623,
    "fromMultiPlanner": true,
    "replanned": true,
    "numYield": 251263,
    "locks": {
        "Global": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": NumberLong(502528)
            }
        },
        "Database": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": NumberLong(251264)
            }
        },
        "Collection": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": NumberLong(251264)
            }
        }
    },
    "nreturned": 101,
    "responseLength": 7476,
    "protocol": "op_query",
    "millis": 35504,
    "planSummary": "IXSCAN { companyId: 1, salaryMonth: 1, employeeId: 1 }",
    "execStats": {
        "stage": "PROJECTION",
        "nReturned": 101,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 27861,
        "works": 29726623,
        "advanced": 101,
        "needTime": 29726522,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 251264,
        "restoreState": 251263,
        "isEOF": 0,
        "invalidates": 0,
        "transformBy": {
            "employeeId": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "amount": 1
        },
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "filter": {
                "$and": [{
                        "companyId": {
                            "$eq": ObjectId("60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5")
                        }
                    }, {
                        "salaryMonth": {
                            "$eq": "2022-09"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned": 101,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 27387,
            "works": 29726623,
            "advanced": 101,
            "needTime": 29726522,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 251264,
            "restoreState": 251263,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "docsExamined": 29726623,
            "alreadyHasObj": 0,
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned": 29726623,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 9654,
                "works": 29726623,
                "advanced": 29726623,
                "needTime": 0,
                "needYield": 0,
                "saveState": 251264,
                "restoreState": 251263,
                "isEOF": 0,
                "invalidates": 0,
                "keyPattern": {
                    "_id": 1
                },
                "indexName": "_id_",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "_id": []
                },
                "isUnique": true,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "_id": ["[MinKey, MaxKey]"]
                },
                "keysExamined": 29726623,
                "seeks": 1,
                "dupsTested": 0,
                "dupsDropped": 0,
                "seenInvalidated": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "ts": ISODate("2022-09-30T17:34:34.965Z"),
    "client": "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers": [{
            "user": "cowboyUser",
            "db": "cowboy"
        }
    ],
    "user": "cowboyUser@cowboy"
}
```

but more wired thing is, if the results item less than about 80000, the query is fast, the only different condition is 'salaryMonth', the former one is '2022-09', below is '2020-08'. '2022-09' condition will find 88078 items, but '2022-08' will find 71678 items. These results is not far different, but first query is so slow(27+ sec), the 2rd query just less than 1 sec. The 2rd query as below:

```
{
    "op": "query",
    "ns": "cowboy.dailyWork",
    "query": {
        "find": "dailyWork",
        "filter": {
            "$and": [{
                    "companyId": ObjectId("60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5")
                }, {
                    "salaryMonth": "2022-08"
                }
            ]
        },
        "sort": {
            "_id": 1
        },
        "projection": {
            "employeeId": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "amount": 1
        },
        "returnKey": false,
        "showRecordId": false
    },
    "cursorid": 71019107321,
    "keysExamined": 71678,
    "docsExamined": 71678,
    "hasSortStage": true,
    "numYield": 563,
    "locks": {
        "Global": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": NumberLong(1128)
            }
        },
        "Database": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": NumberLong(564)
            }
        },
        "Collection": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": NumberLong(564)
            }
        }
    },
    "nreturned": 101,
    "responseLength": 7872,
    "protocol": "op_query",
    "millis": 415,
    "planSummary": "IXSCAN { companyId: 1, salaryMonth: 1, employeeId: 1 }",
    "execStats": {
        "stage": "CACHED_PLAN",
        "nReturned": 101,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 413,
        "works": 101,
        "advanced": 101,
        "needTime": 0,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 564,
        "restoreState": 563,
        "isEOF": 0,
        "invalidates": 0,
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "PROJECTION",
            "nReturned": 101,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 413,
            "works": 71781,
            "advanced": 101,
            "needTime": 71680,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 564,
            "restoreState": 563,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "transformBy": {
                "employeeId": 1,
                "price": 1,
                "amount": 1
            },
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "SORT",
                "nReturned": 101,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 413,
                "works": 71781,
                "advanced": 101,
                "needTime": 71680,
                "needYield": 0,
                "saveState": 564,
                "restoreState": 563,
                "isEOF": 0,
                "invalidates": 0,
                "sortPattern": {
                    "_id": 1
                },
                "memUsage": 32000792,
                "memLimit": 33554432,
                "inputStage": {
                    "stage": "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "nReturned": 71678,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 212,
                    "works": 71680,
                    "advanced": 71678,
                    "needTime": 1,
                    "needYield": 0,
                    "saveState": 564,
                    "restoreState": 563,
                    "isEOF": 1,
                    "invalidates": 0,
                    "inputStage": {
                        "stage": "FETCH",
                        "nReturned": 71678,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 170,
                        "works": 71679,
                        "advanced": 71678,
                        "needTime": 0,
                        "needYield": 0,
                        "saveState": 564,
                        "restoreState": 563,
                        "isEOF": 1,
                        "invalidates": 0,
                        "docsExamined": 71678,
                        "alreadyHasObj": 0,
                        "inputStage": {
                            "stage": "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned": 71678,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 60,
                            "works": 71679,
                            "advanced": 71678,
                            "needTime": 0,
                            "needYield": 0,
                            "saveState": 564,
                            "restoreState": 563,
                            "isEOF": 1,
                            "invalidates": 0,
                            "keyPattern": {
                                "companyId": 1,
                                "salaryMonth": 1,
                                "employeeId": 1
                            },
                            "indexName": "companyId_1_salaryMonth_1_employeeId_1",
                            "isMultiKey": false,
                            "multiKeyPaths": {
                                "companyId": [],
                                "salaryMonth": [],
                                "employeeId": []
                            },
                            "isUnique": false,
                            "isSparse": false,
                            "isPartial": false,
                            "indexVersion": 2,
                            "direction": "forward",
                            "indexBounds": {
                                "companyId": ["[ObjectId('60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5'), ObjectId('60fe62de551f6014f5ff9af5')]"],
                                "salaryMonth": ["[\"2022-08\", \"2022-08\"]"],
                                "employeeId": ["[MinKey, MaxKey]"]
                            },
                            "keysExamined": 71678,
                            "seeks": 1,
                            "dupsTested": 0,
                            "dupsDropped": 0,
                            "seenInvalidated": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "ts": ISODate("2022-09-30T17:52:33.762Z"),
    "client": "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers": [{
            "user": "cowboyUser",
            "db": "cowboy"
        }
    ],
    "user": "cowboyUser@cowboy"
}
```

I have enough RAM, the only different is result items amount. If the result amount more than 80000, the query become very slow. If you know what's going on, please tell me, thanks!

Environment:

- mongodb version 3.4.10
- Disk data: 140GB
- RAM: 64GB
- 16x cpu

Answer (score 0):

The explain output you've provided does not include the `.sort({ "_id": 1 })` clause that is present in your full query. To that end, you should create the following index:

```
{ "companyId" : 1, "salaryMonth" : 1, "_id": 1 }
```

This should also help solve the second part of your problem which is seemingly that planning the query itself also seems to be taking some time. We can see in the second query you provided that `CACHED_PLAN` is present indicating that some of the query planning work was avoided. The index proposed above should help make the query much more efficient overall, which should have the added benefit of making the query planning process faster as well.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I even didn't notice `.sort({ "_id": 1 })` .But I don't get it, in my node code, I don't add sort clause, how dose it come from? Here is my node code:  `const dailyworkParam = { where: {and: [{ companyId: user.companyId, }, {salaryMonth: data.selectMonth }]}, fields: { employeeId: true, price: true,  amount: true }};`  And I don't know why the first and second queries went different plans? It's same node code and same workflow, just different 'salaryMonth' variable.

Comment: Something in the application code is adding a sort as the database won't inject one on its own. But there isn't enough information here to say where specifically that's coming from. Could also be a middle library, since the `where` part of that code snippet doesn't look like something that native drivers use. The fact that the two queries have different plans is just part of how databases operate. Neither is a good plan for the query that includes the sort, so either get the sort removed or create the suggested here. Doing one of those two things should help resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. And I find some essay prove your point,_The number of "work units" performed by the query execution plan during the trial period when the query planner evaluates candidate plans._ The two queries' work units are different, so them execute different plans. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, glad to help! If this answered the question please do accept it so that others know the issue is resolved